# Extending internal method

Tags: python

I am using the dpkt module. dpkt decodes pcapng packets. It is not complete in all areas and it has not been written in a way that is easy to extend.

Consider action_parser in the Action.unpack method below. It only supports a few of the possible options (just block ack, there are loads more categories and codes). It raises exceptions for any other cases. This isn't helpful as it is within the constructor of the IEEE80211 class (**init** calls IEEE80211.unpack calls Action.unpack) so you never get even partial decoding. I would like to extend action_parser to include more options.

Is there some magic that would let me change the value of action_parser from my code?

Or can anyone think of any other way to extend this code?

Probably the proper answer, as dpkt is open source, is to submit changes to the main repo, but I've never done that and not keen to go down that road.

```
class IEEE80211(dpkt.Packet):

    <snip>

    def unpack(self, buf):
        dpkt.Packet.unpack(self, buf)
        self.data = buf[self.__hdr_len__:]

        m_decoder = {
            M_BEACON: ('beacon', self.Beacon),
            M_ASSOC_REQ: ('assoc_req', self.Assoc_Req),
            M_ASSOC_RESP: ('assoc_resp', self.Assoc_Resp),
            M_DISASSOC: ('diassoc', self.Disassoc),
            M_REASSOC_REQ: ('reassoc_req', self.Reassoc_Req),
            M_REASSOC_RESP: ('reassoc_resp', self.Assoc_Resp),
            M_AUTH: ('auth', self.Auth),
            M_PROBE_RESP: ('probe_resp', self.Beacon),
            M_DEAUTH: ('deauth', self.Deauth),
            M_ACTION: ('action', self.Action)
        }

        <snip>

        decoder = {
            MGMT_TYPE: m_decoder,
            CTL_TYPE: c_decoder,
            DATA_TYPE: d_decoder
        }

        <snip>
        try:
            parser = decoder[self.type][self.subtype][1]
            name = decoder[self.type][self.subtype][0]
        except KeyError:
            raise dpkt.UnpackError("KeyError: type=%s subtype=%s" % (self.type, self.subtype))

    class Action(dpkt.Packet):
        __hdr__ = (
            ('category', 'B', 0),
            ('code', 'B', 0),
        )

        def unpack(self, buf):
            dpkt.Packet.unpack(self, buf)

            action_parser = {
                BLOCK_ACK: {
                    BLOCK_ACK_CODE_REQUEST: ('block_ack_request', IEEE80211.BlockAckActionRequest),
                    BLOCK_ACK_CODE_RESPONSE: ('block_ack_response', IEEE80211.BlockAckActionResponse),
                    BLOCK_ACK_CODE_DELBA: ('block_ack_delba', IEEE80211.BlockAckActionDelba),
                },
            }

            try:
                decoder = action_parser[self.category][self.code][1]
                field_name = action_parser[self.category][self.code][0]
            except KeyError:
                raise dpkt.UnpackError("KeyError: category=%s code=%s" % (self.category, self.code))
```

Comment: Make a subclass and overwrite the unpack method as you like. Google "Python calss inheritance"

Comment: I can derive a child class from IEEE80211.Action and override its unpack method,. But then I've also got to subclass IEEE80211 and override its unpack method to change m_decoder to use my Action class. That's a bit ugly. Or have I missed something, can this be done in a clean & simple way?

Comment: That's how you do it. I don't see a cleaner way. You have to override the methods.